# Android Vector Drawables becoming blurry when resize to lagre scale

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to use this world map [svg](http://mapsvg.com/maps/geo-calibrated/world.svg), however it is not scaling when I resize the vector to see Singapore. The map become blurry. More specific I set the width and height of imageView to 36000dp.

Here is the width and height of vector drawbles:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="2000dp"
    android:height="1001dp"
    android:viewportWidth="2000"
    android:viewportHeight="1001">
```

In my Layout file, I already use app:srcCompat instead of src: .

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#3A6F5C">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Map_svg"
        android:layout_width="36000dp"
        android:layout_height="36000dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_world_map"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.example.alan_lin.flora_shipanimation"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

How can I stop it from becoming blurry when I upscale it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried the SVG you shared, but it is too complicated to be handled by Android, the app crashes when it tried to load it on runtime saying a `STRING_TOO_LARGE` int the stack trace.

For your solution, I would suggest using PNGs for these kinds of very complex SVGs.

Two more notes:

1. If you are using a normal size vector don't forget to set the `android:scaleType` attribute to your `ImageView`.
2. Don't forget to add this line of code in your `Application` extension:

   ```
    public class App extends Application {

    static {
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    }
    ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I need to use other SVG. I tried the notes you mention above, however it didn't help to make vector drawable become not blur.